# Stack len function (linked list)

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a stack using a linked list but I seem to run into a problem with my `__len__` function, when I try using `len(s)` when I run my code it just tells me 'Stack' object has no attribute 'size'. Am I getting the size of the stack wrong? I'm not sure.

```
class Node:
"""A node for a linked list."""

def __init__(self, item):
    self.item = item
    self.next_node = None


class Stack(object):
        
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

   

    def __len__(self):
        """ Returns the length --- calling len(s) will invoke this method """
        return self.size
```

Comment: Which part of that code do you think might be setting or maintaining `size`?  Do you think `push` and `pop` might need to maintain it (and `__init__` initialise it)?

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: In your specific case, the problem can be demonstrated in a single line of code, therefore, posting 30 lines of code is excessive. Also, do you *really* believe that `# ---start student section---` or `# ===end student section===` is what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implementing this data structure yourself, you will want to also track the size yourself. Try initializing `self.size` to 0, then add or subtract one from `size` each time you add or subtract a node. In this case, that would mean incrementing `size` in the `push` method, and decrementing `size` in the `pop` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because `self.size` which you are referring in `__len__` is not define anywhere. It should be something like this -

```
class Stack(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0
```